# Get the list of compiled modules? Exclude React from bundle?

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

How to get the list of compiled modules bundled with browserify + babelify?
I've set a simple bundling process with gulp.

I noticed that the bundle becomes very big. I don't have a lot of 'useful' code. From libraries I have the following on the page: React, react-router, validator and EventEmitter, Immutable. But the bundle is about 1.5MBs. The map file is separate. Is there a way to minimize the size?

I tried to exclude React with:

```
bundleStream.external(['jquery', 'react']);
```

I saw that jquery was excluded and the size is smaller now. I still see React modules in output.

#### UPDATE

So, my problem was that I also used a few react components added via npm. One of those was pointing to *'react'* and the other *'react/addons'*. I figured that manually going through the code. Not sure which tool could help me with that. So to strip it I had to add both to my browserify bundle:

```
bundleStream.external(['jquery', 'react', 'react/addons']);
```

One thing to mention though is that my goal was to load the libraries from CDN and just use theirs globals in my code. I've written a simple browserify transform function like explained [here](https://github.com/benbria/browserify-transform-tools) to change all **require('react')** or **import React from 'react'** lines to global **window.React**, but it didn't work out with *require* calls inside those react components from npm. So like half of the bundle contained *window.React* and the other still *require('react')* lines.

To fix that I piped the bundle after *babelify* transform to *[replaceStream](https://github.com/eugeneware/replacestream)* like so:

```
.pipe(replaceStream('require("react")', 'window.React'))
```

Answer (score 1):

These links may help you.

- [Running minified file in development](https://christianalfoni.github.io/react-webpack-cookbook/Optimizing-rebundling.html)
- [Split app and vendors](https://christianalfoni.github.io/react-webpack-cookbook/Split-app-and-vendors.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I have been searching for.